# Keep getting ReferenceError: fter is not defined

Tags: referenceerror

My filter function sends in the two parameters I want to be used in my filter.sql but to no avail it always returns this. At some point I cannot figure out my parameters does not get to the controller file. It is defined before sent off to the endpoint but as it tries to use that value in the controller function it says not defined.

**First filter function:**

```
handleFilter() {
console.log(this.state.filter);
console.log(this.state.filterText);
if (this.props.searchText === "") {
  axios
    .post("/api/filter", { fText: this.state.filterText, fter: 
this.state.filter })
    .then(response => {
      this.props.updateCSR(response.data);
      updateFPO(this.props.filterPopout === false ? true : false);
    });
} else {
  axios
    .post(
    "/api/sfilter",
    {
      fText: this.state.filterText,
      fter: this.state.filter,
      sText: this.props.searchText
    }
    )
    .then(response => {
      this.props.updateCSR(response.data);
      updateFPO(this.props.filterPopout === false ? true : false);
    });
  }
  }
```

**Endpoint**:

```
app.post("/api/filter", ic.filter);
app.post("/api/sfilter", ic.sfilter);
```

**Filter in Controller:**

```
filter: (req, res, next) => {
const { filter, filterText } = req.body;
const dbInstance = req.app.get("db");
dbInstance
  .filter([fter, fText])
  .then(resp => {
    res.status(200).send(resp);
  })
  .catch(() => res.status(500).send());
 },
 sfilter: (req, res, next) => {
 const { fter, fText, sText } = req.body;
 const dbInstance = req.app.get("db");
 dbInstance
  .sfilter([fter, fText, sText])
  .then(resp => {
    res.status(200).send(resp);
  })
  .catch(() => res.status(500).send());
 }
```

The error on the console for the front end is

```
 POST http://localhost:3000/api/filter 500 (Internal Server Error)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:178
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:12
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:52
Promise resolved (async)
request @ Axios.js:58
Axios.(anonymous function) @ Axios.js:78
wrap @ bind.js:9
handleFilter @ Filter.js:33
onClick @ Filter.js:79
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:1299
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:1338
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:1195
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:1209
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:1432
executeDispatchesInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:1454
executeDispatchesAndRelease @ react-dom.development.js:1969
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:1980
forEachAccumulated @ react-dom.development.js:1946
processEventQueue @ react-dom.development.js:2139
runEventQueueInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:2151
handleTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:2161
handleTopLevelImpl @ react-dom.development.js:1800
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:13238
performFiberBatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:1646
stackBatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:1637
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:1651
batchedUpdatesWithControlledComponents @ react-dom.development.js:1664
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:1874
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:77)
```

What is going on here? I have had this problem in other places but I cannot ignore it now. I have to fix it but it is not complying!!

Thanks for your time!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, maybe you need to change to the following? :

```
dbInstance
  .filter([filter, filterText])
  .then(resp => {
    res.status(200).send(resp);
  })
  .catch(() => res.status(500).send());
 },
```

Since it looks to me like at that point `fter` and `fText` aren't defined yet, but `filter` and `filterText` are so you probably meant to use them.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I changed this. (I thought I changed this earlier). It is still broken though. :( I get the error that I am updating my message with. I forgot to include that.